# I have to wait 1 minute, before iPhone app starts, using Xcode 12

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode12

I have one problem. When i run my project, it shows black screen, which disappears in 1 minute. I use cable to run, but on simulator same effect. Also i use Xcode 12. I tried to turn off option "Debug executable", but I can't use all debug functions. Is there way to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I delete all objects from folder ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport. After that, everything start to work normally.